# Make nested scrollview not scroll completely

Tags: android, xml

In my activity XML I have a **Collapsing toolbar** and, after that, an  referring to my other XML where I have a **NestedScrollView**.
This is an image of the collapsing toolbar when it is **NOT** collapsed.

[image]

When I scroll up, it becomes collapsed and the NestedSrollView appears like this:

[image]

I want it to scroll just to some point like this and after that the user cannot scroll more:

[image]

How can I achieve this?
This is my main XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayoutCountryInfo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparadetail"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparadetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparadetail"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbardetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPhotoDetailFundo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPhotoDetailEscuro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_pais_info"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEscuroPhotoDetailTopo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleX="2"
            android:scaleY="-1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blur_paises_filtro" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbariddetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
            android:id="@+id/blurViewDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:realtimeBlurRadius="10dp"
            app:realtimeOverlayColor="#8000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNomePaisDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/txtNomeContinente"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDefinicao"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparainfo"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgVoltarPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_back_branca" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgApagarPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="355dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/txtDefinicao"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include
    layout="@layout/content_scrolling_photo_detail"
/>
```

And **this** is my include

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to NestedScrollView Child... See my below code as an example...

```
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

---

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/> // add this line to NestedScrollView child
       </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```